# Замена цветов во всем интерфейсе приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `WPF` приложение, выполненное в определенном визуальном стиле например, фон у всех окон и страниц серый. Можно ли, и если можно то как наиболее эффективно сменить этот фон на всех окнах разом, даже если обьекты `page` или `window` еще не созданы ?

Comment: Переменная? О.о

Comment: Если все цвета устанавливаются через стили — да. Или, скажем, через `DynamicResource`.

Comment: Вы наверное имеете ввиду темы?

Comment: @VladD думал об этом. Но как поменять стиль через код ?желательно что бы сохранить при последующем запуске. а значит нужно хранить цвета не в стиле а в отдельном файле?

Comment: @FoggyFinder под темы вы понимаете обьекты .NET ?

Comment: Нет, я понимаю `Theme`. [Пример](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html)

Comment: @FoggyFinder не знал об этом, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы хотите, называется *стилизация* приложения. Она не получится просто так, придётся поработать.

Последовательность действий может быть такая:

1. Значения всех визуальных свойств положите в стили.
2. Стили соберите в `ResourceDictionary` (назовём его `skin1.xaml`)
3. Подключайте все стили из `skin1.xaml` через `DynamicResource`.
4. Разработайте альтернативные стили, дайте им такие же имена, и положите в соседний `ResourceDictionary` (назовём его `skin2.xaml`)
5. В начале работы приложения определите, хотите ли вы работать со skin1 или skin2
6. Подгрузите в App.xaml в `Resources` `skin1.xaml` или `skin2.xaml` в `MergedDictionaries`.
7. Если вы хотите сменить цвета во время пробега программы, добавьте в `MergedDictionaries` другой `ResourceDictionary`, после чего уберите старый.